# pyinquirer 1.0.3 requires prompt_toolkit==1.0.14, but you have prompt-toolkit 3.0.28 which is incompatible

Tags: python, pip, vpython

Trying to figure out how to programmatically generate 3D models, found a series of YouTube tutorials using vpython, tried to install vpython. `pip install vpython` It installs, most of it looks fine.

```
Collecting vpython
  Downloading vpython-7.6.3-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (3.6 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.6/3.6 MB 957.3 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting ipykernel
  Downloading ipykernel-6.9.2-py3-none-any.whl (130 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 130.2/130.2 KB 768.7 kB/s eta 0:00:00
... etc. etc.
Successfully installed MarkupSafe-2.1.1 Send2Trash-1.8.0 aiohttp-3.8.1 aiosignal-1.2.0 anyio-3.5.0 argon2-cffi-21.3.0 argon2-cffi-bindings-21.2.0 asttokens-2.0.5 async-timeout-4.0.2 attrs-21.4.0 autobahn-22.2.2 backcall-0.2.0 beautifulsoup4-4.10.0 bleach-4.1.0 cffi-1.15.0 charset-normalizer-2.0.12 colorama-0.4.4 cryptography-36.0.2 debugpy-1.6.0 decorator-5.1.1 entrypoints-0.4 executing-0.8.3 frozenlist-1.3.0 hyperlink-21.0.0 idna-3.3 ipykernel-6.9.2 ipython-8.1.1 ipython-genutils-0.2.0 ipywidgets-7.7.0 jedi-0.18.1 jinja2-3.1.1 jsonschema-4.4.0 jupyter-1.0.0 jupyter-client-7.1.2 jupyter-console-6.4.3 jupyter-core-4.9.2 jupyter-server-1.15.6 jupyter-server-proxy-3.2.1 jupyterlab-pygments-0.1.2 jupyterlab-widgets-1.1.0 matplotlib-inline-0.1.3 mistune-0.8.4 multidict-6.0.2 nbclient-0.5.13 nbconvert-6.4.4 nbformat-5.2.0 nest-asyncio-1.5.4 notebook-6.4.10 numpy-1.22.3 packaging-21.3 pandocfilters-1.5.0 parso-0.8.3 pickleshare-0.7.5 prometheus-client-0.13.1 prompt-toolkit-3.0.28 psutil-5.9.0 pure-eval-0.2.2 pycparser-2.21 pyparsing-3.0.7 pyrsistent-0.18.1 python-dateutil-2.8.2 pywin32-303 pywinpty-2.0.5 pyzmq-22.3.0 qtconsole-5.2.2 qtpy-2.0.1 simpervisor-0.4 sniffio-1.2.0 soupsieve-2.3.1 stack-data-0.2.0 terminado-0.13.3 testpath-0.6.0 tornado-6.1 traitlets-5.1.1 txaio-22.2.1 vpython-7.6.3 webencodings-0.5.1 websocket-client-1.3.1 widgetsnbextension-3.6.0 yarl-1.7.2
```

Except for:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
pyinquirer 1.0.3 requires prompt_toolkit==1.0.14, but you have prompt-toolkit 3.0.28 which is incompatible.
```

Should I be concerned? What can I do about this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+requires+but+you+have+which+is+incompatible.

Comment: `pip install --upgrade vpython` to allow `pip` to upgrade/downgrade dependencies.